# How to check if useRouter can use router.back() in nextjs app

Tags: next.js

- I'm using next js for my application and I'm facing some issues with routing to the previous route of the application. I know that there is a function like ***`router.back()`***, but I do not know if I can go back from the current page.
- I have read that we can check **`history.action !== 'POP'`** but now I check that history has no action property when using console.log(history)

I am using next/router.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update Dec 2023:**

It appears the history.state.idx method no longer works, currently this is doable with the following:

```
if (window.history?.length) {
   router.back();
} else {
   router.replace(href || "/");
}
```

**Original:**

Way too late to be useful but for the next person that comes along: If I read your question correctly, you're wanting to know if there is something in the navigation stack that you can navigate back to - and you want to do something else if there is no history.

You can use window.history.state to get a glimpse; although it doesn't give you clear access to the history stack the state has an "idx" property that is incremented when a location is added to the history stack. This means that if window.history.state.idx is zero there's nothing in the history stack, if it's bigger than zero then there is something in the history stack and you can navigate back.

An example for navigating back if you can or doing something else if not:

```
if (window.history.state && window.history.state.idx > 0) {
    router.back();
} else {
    // Do something else              
}
```